# How can I create two formatted dictionaries from a user input CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, format, tuples

Create a Python solution to the following task. Ensure that the solution produces output in exactly the same format shown in the sample(s) below, including capitalization and whitespace.

Task:
Create a solution that accepts an input identifying the name of a CSV file, for example, "input1.csv". Each file contains two rows of comma-separated values. Import the built-in module csv and use its open() function and reader() method to create a dictionary of key:value pairs for each row of comma-separated values in the specified file. Output the file contents as two dictionaries.

The solution output should be in the format

```
{'key': 'value', 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'}
{'key': 'value', 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'}
```

The input file used below is:

```
 a, 100, b, 200, c, 300
bananas, 1.85, steak, 19.99, cookies, 4.52
```

Now, I've found solutions online to parts of the problem, but nothing that address each issue that this item asks for. I've tried ChatGPT and it can't figure it out and I've tried modifying codes for two days now and I can't seem to figure this out.

The problem says that the results need to output exactly like this (including all punctuation and whitespace):

```
{'a': '100', 'b': '200', 'c': '300'}
{'bananas': '1.85', 'steak': '19.99', 'cookies': '4.52'}
```

So, here's ChatGPT's attempt (with comments removed):

```
import csv
csv_file_name = input()
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
with open(csv_file_name, 'r') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)   
    for row in csv_reader:
        dict1[row[0]] = row[1]
        dict2[row[2]] = row[3]
print(dict1)
print(dict2)
```

But that results in output of:

```
{' a': ' 100', 'bananas': ' 1.85'}
{' b': ' 200', ' steak': ' 19.99'}
```

So, then I tried:

```
import csv
filename = input()
with open(filename, 'r') as data:
    for line in csv.DictReader(data):
        print(line)
```

But I ran it and got:

```
{' a': 'bananas', ' 100': ' 1.85', ' b': ' steak', ' 200': ' 19.99', ' c': ' cookies', ' 300': ' 4.52'}
```

So, then I tried:

```
import csv
filename = input()
with open(filename, 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(read_obj)
    list_of_csv = list(csv_reader)
    print(list_of_csv)
```

And I got:

```
[[' a', ' 100', ' b', ' 200', ' c', ' 300'], ['bananas', ' 1.85', ' steak', ' 19.99', ' cookies', ' 4.52']]
```

which is almost right, but I need to line break after the tuples, remove the brackets and whitespaces and add the colons. I keep getting error when I try to put split() in the code anywhere and other formatting solutions don't seem to work with dictionary outputs. I still need to be able to output as two dictionaries.

Comment: "I keep getting error" what is the error?

Comment: What does the input file exactly look like?

Comment: Please include the input file in the answer

Comment: Hint: read the documentation for `csv.reader`. There is a parameter that can help.

Comment: Don't waste your time with ChatGPT. It doesn't know how to program any better than you do.

Comment: @Barmar I love chatty g but it definitely has blind spots

Comment: ChatGPT is a plausible text generator. You have to fact check everything it generates.

Comment: Apparently the CSV file has spaces after the commas. The problem specification doesn't make any mention of removing them, but it appears to be an unstated requirement if your results aren't acceptable. `csv.reader()` doesn't do this automatically by default.

Comment: @MarkTolonen That's the problem -- if you don't know how to program, you can't tell when its answer is nonsense. It has this same problem in any area -- if you don't know history, you can't tell when it's reporting it wrong.

Comment: @Barmar That was my point.  "Plausible".  It sounds good but is often incorrect.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I was agreeing with you.

Comment: Now I know that the original file is: 
[' a', ' 100', ' b', ' 200', ' c', ' 300']
['bananas', ' 1.85', ' steak', ' 19.99', ' cookies', ' 4.52']

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your `input1.csv` looks like this:

```
 a, 100, b, 200, c, 300
bananas, 1.85, steak, 19.99, cookies, 4.52
```

Without giving away the answer to your assignment directly, consider that `range(0, len(some_list), 2)` will yield the index of every other item in that list. For example:

```py
some_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for index in range(0, len(some_list), 2):
    print(some_list[index])
```

Output:

```
1
3
```

Try to figure out where you might be able to use this idea.

Comment: I couldn't get that to produce anything other than one letter per line outputs. I'm trying to learn this stuff, so I don't know what I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints since this looks like homework:

1. [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) has [formatting parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters) to deal with spaces after delimiters.
2. Each line has alternating key/value pairs.  [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) can help. In particular the *step* option, e.g., `row[::2]` to get every other item.
3. [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) can create key/value pairs.
4. [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) can take list of keys and list of values and pair them up.